# Use Asset field as a Global Set Variable?

Tags: assets, globals

Is it possible to use an Asset field as a Global Set? For example:

```
{{ companyInfo.logo }}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `companyInfo` if your global and `logo` if your Asset field, then you'd use it just like you would [anywhere else](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/assets-fields#templating) keeping in mind that all relation fields (Assets, Users, Entries, Tags, Categories, etc.) always return a *collection* of results.

So, `companyInfo.logo.first()` will return the first asset and if you want to loop through them all:

```
{% for image in companyInfo.logo %}
    {{ image.getUrl() }}<br />        
{% endfor %}
```